# How to access _getFormFields from nsILoginManager for My Addons Use?

Tags: firefox-addon

Hi all I want to use the function _getFormFields from nsiLoginManager:
http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/components/passwordmgr/nsLoginManager.js

How can I tap into it to use utilize this function for my need?

So bascially I'm wanting to use the private components from nsILoginManager for my own needs. I also need to use _fillDocument and _getPasswordOrigin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These methods are prefixed with an underscore to indicate that these are private and not meant to be used from outside. In fact, they aren't part of the [nsILoginManager interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsILoginManager) which means that you cannot access them. So if you need the `_getPasswordOrigin` function you should just copy the code into your extension.

However, the `_getFormFields` and `_fillDocument` functions aren't actually part of the `LoginManager` component but rather defined in the [`LoginManagerContent.jsm` module](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/passwordmgr/LoginManagerContent.jsm). That module isn't access via an interface, so you can access private methods as well:

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/LoginManagerContent.jsm");
LoginManagerContent._getFormFields(...);
LoginManagerContent._fillDocument(...);
```

Note that these methods are private for a reason - they might go away in a future Firefox version or start doing something entirely different. In fact, the entire module is an implementation detail and might go away any time. So you should seriously consider any alternatives you might have.

Comment: Ah superb!! Thanks wlad! I've been looking to use these functions found in JSM for a long time! I posted on mozilla google group never heard back. Reason I needed to use the private version is because some of functions there were using the private methods. The JSM wont go away in future will it?

Comment: It looks like i can copy paste _getPasswordOrigin it doesnt rely on any private members but out of curiosity is it possible o use LoginUtils._getPasswordOrigin from the JSM? [its here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/passwordmgr/LoginManagerContent.jsm#767)